# JSON parsing gives me JsonSyntaxException

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson, illegalstateexception

I'm trying to convert a response String with a JSON inside to an Object, using Gson, but I'm facing an exception, that I think that have been caused by the double quotes or something.

Te result to convert is like:

```
    {
  "params": {
    "data": {
      "user": "USER01",
      "token": "924e24fdd200760b3bb",
      "language": "es-ES"
    },
    "path": "funds",
    "method": "POST",
    "okCallback": "SUCESS",
    "koCallback": "ERROR"
  }
}
```

I have a custom object to parse this response.

```
public class HybridParams {

    @SerializedName("method")
    @Expose
    private String method;
    @SerializedName("path")
    @Expose
    private String path;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private String data;
    @SerializedName("okCallback")
    @Expose
    private String okCallback;
    @SerializedName("koCallback")
    @Expose
    private String koCallback;
```

And I'm trying to do:

```
new Gson().fromJson(requestJson, HybridRequest.class);
```

But I'm getting and error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 20 path $.params.data
```

Any advice?? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to deserialize the data object in JSON to a String object. Define a class for the Data object and change the data type in your HybridParams.

```
@Expose
private DataParams data;
```

And the Data class:

```
public class DataParams {

    @Expose
    private String user;
    @Expose
    private String token;
    @Expose
    private String language;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this "data" maybe change the parameters. :(

Comment: If your data object hasn't the same attributes each time, maybe you can change it to a JsonObject (no need to DataParams class then) and deserialize it according to the field it contains into some other classes later.

Answer (score 0):

Your **data** field is object and you try cast that String so only you get this error.

You should try to achieve this,

```
@SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private YourNewObject data;
```

You can parse user, token and language from that YourNewObject

Answer (score 0):

The data is a JSON object. But you are parsing it under String data type.
Therefore, Error: Expected a STRING, but was BEGIN_OBJECT; which means the compiler was expecting a String ( as defined by YOU ), but was a BEGIN_OBJECT (as in the data).
Your solution is to change either the definition, or the data so that they both match.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Romain's answer is correct, but just want to say something about @SerializedName and @Expose.

You don't have to use both annotations in your case.

```
@SerializedName("method")
@Expose
private String method;
```

is the same as:

```
@Expose
private String method;
```

So, @Expose is included in @SerializedName, no need for both.

If you're fine with API property in this case 'method', no need to add @SerializedName.

If API property has a different name than you Class property, than you use @SerilizedName (and you can avoid @Expose).

@Expose has also one more role. JSON parser works in two directions, serialize and deserialize, and you can disable one direction with @Expose(serialize=false) or @Expose(deserialize=false)